# How to combine a ContourPlot with a Manipulate[Parametric Plot]

Tags: manipulate, physics, parametric-functions, graphics

I have this code of an orbit at a Lagrange Point of the Sun-Jupiter system

```
Alpha = 0.000953875;
r01[x_, y_] := Sqrt[(x - Alpha)^2 + y^2];
r02[x_, y_] := Sqrt[(x + 1 - Alpha)^2 + y^2];
x00 = -0.509;      
y00 = 0.883;
u00 = 0.0259;
v00 = 0.0149;
tmax = 600;


solution = NDSolve[{x'[t] == u[t], y'[t] == v[t], 
u'[t] == (-(1 - Alpha) (x[t] - Alpha))/r01[x[t], y[t]]^3 - (
  Alpha (x[t] + 1 - Alpha))/r02[x[t], y[t]]^3 + x[t] + 2 v[t],

v'[t] == -(((1 - Alpha) y[t])/r01[x[t], y[t]]^3 ) - (Alpha y[t])/
  r02[x[t], y[t]]^3 + y[t] - 2 u[t], 

x[0] == x00, y[0] == y00, 
u[0] == u00, v[0] == v00}, {x, y, u, v}, {t, 0, tmax}];
```

and i can manipulate said result with this code

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. solution], {t, 0, b}, 
PlotRange -> {{-0.9, -0.1}, {0.4, 1}}], {b, 0.01, 150}]
```

[image]

I also have a contour plot

```
plot1 = ContourPlot[-((1 - a)/Sqrt[(x - a)^2 + y^2]) - a/
Sqrt[(x + 1 - a)^2 + y^2] - 1/2 (x^2 + y^2), {x, -1.65, 
1.65}, {y, -1.65, 1.65}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

Using the `Show` command, i cant manage to put them together, it says "Could not combine the graphics objects in Show", how can i combine them?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have tried to combine ContourPlot with Manipulate. This will not work because Show cannot combine a Graphics object with a Manipulate object. Instead have Show inside Manipulate itself.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[plot1, 
  ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. solution], {t, 0, b}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.9, -0.1}, {0.4, 1}}]], {b, 0.01, 150}]
```

BTW your code for ContourPlot does not have the value for a. I took a to be 1 just to check.

Comment: YES! Thank you so much! You're right, i forgot the value of a ,it was 0.001. Say, you helped me to show one orbit in that ContourPlot, i have other 4 solutions that cover other 4 areas of said ContourPlot, named "solution1, solution2, etc,.." How do i plot them altogether each, with its manipulate, in the ContourPlot? Should i make a list of 4 ParametricPlots?

Comment: It seems like you can solve the equations to get all 4 solutions and plot them all together using one ParametricPlot. and Use ContourPlot to show the contours. Manipuate can be wrapped Show as before.